# vuejs onclick behaviour on template's component

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, onclick

I have some issue during developing vue's template onclick event. So, i can open module when I click the file, I have seen some sample with native. unfortunately, still not suit into my code and can't reach into console. here's my code :

I try to add native but still no response on console log.

**html**

```
<div id="app">
<notification :notice="notice" ></notification>
</div>
```

**js**

```
const myTest = [ 
  {
    title: 'mamam',
    body: 'Mamamia',
    type: 'success'
  },{
    title: 'Perlu',
    body: 'Hati-hati sedang ada perbaikan',
    type: 'Danger'
  },{
    title: 'Notification',
    body: 'Repellendus quod aliquid ad, quae harum similique facilis aliquam. Dolorum deserunt alias officia atque dolor, voluptas harum. Inventore reiciendis reprehenderit provident!',
    type: 'primary'
  } 
];

function randomInt(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
};

Vue.component('notification', {
  template: 
  `
  <div class="Notification" v-show="notice">
    <div class="notice" :class="notice.type">
      <svg @click="notice=!notice" class="close" width="20" height="20" viewbox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="2">
        <line x1="3" y1="3" x2="17" y2="17"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="17" x2="17" y2="3"></line>
      </svg>
      <div class="title">
        <i class="type" :class="notice.type">{{notice.type}}</i>
        {{notice.title}}
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <i class="type" :class="notice.type">{{notice.body}}</i>
        <a @click.native="showFile"> File </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
     notice: {
      type: [Object, Array]
    },
  },
});

setInterval(() => ( vm.$data.index = randomInt(0, 6) ), randomInt(100, 10000) );

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    index: 0
  },
  computed: {
    notice() {return myTest[this.index]}
  },
  methods: {
        showFile(e) {
          console.log(' show file was clicked. ')
      }
}
});
```

Comment: Grammatical correction

Comment: i know is bad grammatical, just hope you understand my point @SaveenDhiman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1. `showFile` should be defined in notification component. It can't reach parent `showFile` methods

```js
Vue.component('notification', {
      template: 
      `
      <div class="Notification" v-show="notice">
        <div class="notice" :class="notice.type">
          <svg @click="notice=!notice" class="close" width="20" height="20" viewbox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="2">
            <line x1="3" y1="3" x2="17" y2="17"></line>
            <line x1="3" y1="17" x2="17" y2="3"></line>
          </svg>
          <div class="title">
            <i class="type" :class="notice.type">{{notice.type}}</i>
            {{notice.title}}
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <i class="type" :class="notice.type">{{notice.body}}</i>
            <a @click.native="showFile"> File </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `,
      props: {
         notice: {
          type: [Object, Array]
        },
      },
      methods: {
        showFile(e) {
          console.log(' show file was clicked. ')
        }
      }
    });
```

2. You should not mutate `notice` props in children component ([More information](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/avoid-mutating-props-directly/5189))

Comment: thx @ittus, your answer hope me to fix my onclick problem's, but actually i'm using extension data on parent. your code works on statis but the other problem's come when i use external data.
  
var myResponse = [{}];
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  index: 0
  },
  mounted: function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/dir/data-assistant',
      success:function(data){
       myResponse = data;
      }
  })
   
  },  
  computed: {
    notice() {return myResponse[this.index]}
  }
  
});